# Alternatives to SQL Server QUOTENAME command without the limitation of 128 characters. How to put a string between parantheses

Tags: sql-server

Is there any SQL Server function to make the same as QUOTENAME but without the limitation of 128 characters?

Now I have a string that is more than 128 characters and below function fails:

```
DECLARE @myString varchar(max)='''01'',''02'',''03'',''04'',''05'',''06'',''07'',''08'',''09'',''10'',''11'',''12'',''13'',''14'',''15'',''16'',''17'',''18'',''19'',''20'',''21'',''22'',''23'',''24'',''25'',''26'',''27'',''28'',''29'',''30'',''31'',''32'',''33'',''34'',''35'',''36'',''37'',''38'',''39'',''40'',''41'',''42'',''43'',''44'',''45'',''46'',''47'',''48'',''49'',''50'',''51'',''52''';

QUOTENAME(@myString, '()')
```

Obviously QUOTENAME fails because @myString is more than 128 characters, in this case is 260 characters length.

I want to put the string between parantheses.

Comment: If we're being "honest", the above fails as you haven't escaped the majority of your single quotes (`'`) in your literal string.

Comment: *"why downvote?"* I can't tell you why others downvote, @Ralph, and commenting isn't mandatory to vote (up or down). I can only assume the person felt "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful". At a guess I'd suggest that the question does indeed show a lack of research, but the vote isn't mine so I can do little more than guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `REPLACE` and wrap the value with the delimiter characters. `QUOTENAME(@SomeString,'''')` and `N'''' + REPLACE(@SomeString,'''','''''') + N''''` would be equivalent, for example.

For yours, it would be `N'(' + REPLACE(@MyString,')','))') + N')'`.

```sql
SELECT QUOTENAME('Hello(There)','(') AS Quotename,
       N'(' + REPLACE('Hello(There)',')','))') + N')' AS Replace;
```

```
Quotename       Replace
--------------- ---------------
(Hello(There))) (Hello(There)))
```

Notice that for characters that have both left and right characters (such as the parenthesis (`()`) here) you only need to escape the right character, not the left.

Comment: I want to put the string between parantheses. Your solution by conactenating it to N'(' + @myString + N')' is correct for me but I thought in SQL Server there was a better way to do it.

Comment: *"I want to put the string between parantheses"* That's exactly what the above *is* doing, @Ralph . Note that `N'(' + @myString + N')'` does **not** simulate what `QUOTENAME` does; it doesn't escape the characters within the string. If you replaced `QUOTENAME` with that syntax in dynamic SQL, it would be a major security issue.

Comment: Ok, so according to security reasons, is it better to use N'(' + REPLACE('Hello(There)',')','))') + N')' than N'(' + @myString + N')' right? And yes, I am using a dynamic SQL. In which manner it compromises security?

Comment: That is a completely different question, and not suitable for the comments, @Ralph . In short, if you don't escape the character, it can be by someone malicious. I have very recently covered how to use `QUOTENAME` and `REPLACE` for dynamic SQL: [Getting to Grips with Dynamic SQL](https://wp.larnu.uk/getting-to-grips-with-dynamic-sql-the-beginning/)